# Why is Magento not displaying Orders in the admin Backend?

Tags: php, magento, orders

We're using Magento 1.9.1.0 and it recently stopped displaying Orders in the Backend under **Sales**->**Orders**. I can't figure out why this is:

Screen: http://oi58.tinypic.com/ea4605.jpg

- The Orders in the Database seem to be okay. Orders can be placed as usual and they appear in the *Dashboard* under *Last 5 Orders*
- I reuploaded the original backend-templates into `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\`
- Both `var\log\system.log` and `exception.log` show no entries when the page is called
- Other people reported that the grid-view table is only partially loaded until it stops at a faulty data-set and is therefore not displayed, however in my case the page's source contains no more than an empty `<div></div>`

Any hints or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are check for the wrong place for the problem. The problem may have been occurred in the code folder not design folder. First of all have you override or overwrite the "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid"? Because this file is responsible for displaying the order grid. If not your core file may have got corrupted. Try replacing the "Sales" folder from any other installation and check whether the problem is resolved.

If that doesnot resolve the issue than you must have overiden or overwritten the file.

First try the above solution and tell if it works or not.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you, @aton1004 for pointing me to the files involved! My replace template approach was a shot in the dark, it appearently worked for some dude ([link](http://blog.valestudios.com/2011/11/blank-page-in-magento-admin-order-view.html)). I now also replaced the Sales Code Folder with my original files, which worked fine until yesterday. Unfortunately this did also not fix it. By `Mage::log` I found, that in `Grid.php` the function `__construct()` is called and executed, however `_prepareCollection()` and `_prepareColumns()` which appear to contain the construction of the Grid are _not_.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't override the grid.php? May be the function _prepareCollection() and _prepareColumns() are overriden in your local folder.

Comment: You are absolutely right @aton1004 
A module, as described in my own answer posted, does in fact override `Grid.php`. However in my case unfortunately this is the only way it works at all. I was to believe that disabling the module in `System > Advanced` should reverse that and make Magento go back to it's own core adminhtml. Well, if _disabled_ it does neither get to my `Mage::log` in the Module's `Grid.php` nor to the mentioned functions in the Magento's Core `Grid.php`.
If you can explain, I'm intrested to hear why this is. 
Anyway, thank you very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 1):

**Screenshot for admin order details page, If showing this type issue, Please follow below instruction its working for me !!**[image]

**strong text**

> Change line 124 in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php from $links = []; to $links = array();

Answer (score 0):

You can right click after "Orders" and click on Inspect element to see if it's giving you some error.

Comment: Thank you Natalie, however there are no js-errors, failed requests or anything suspicious to detect on the browser-side. Page is called clean and simple, response is displayed without any errors. The thing is, that the returned html in that template is empty. It must therefor be, I believe, a server-side problem while rendering that view.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I resolved this issue myself by random luck:

In the earlier process of trying to fix this my first approach was to *disable* Extensions and Modules. Because I would assume that eliminating possibly interferences will eventually result in being back at the basic stable out-of-the-box magento that has previously worked. Right?

However it turned out only after *reenabling* just one certain module called *PdfGenerator* by *EaDesign* in `System > Advanced > EaDesign_PdfGenerator` the Order-View was restored as usual. It must have had previously interfered with other Modules and only if being the only enabled Module gives me back our Order-View.

Now it riddles me how a Module, of that I don't know why it would affect Order View in the first place, will interfere with the default Order-View if *disabled*, while leaving it be if *enabled*.
In a weird way it appears our magento-store now depends on this module to run in order to produce the Order-Grid-View and can no longer independently do so.

If anyone can elaborate, please do so. I am *very* curious.

Thank you for the help!